# After editing a first post in review, why doesn't the comment link work?

Tags: bug, comments, edits, review

Here's how I ran into what I think might be a bug:

1. Began reviewing First Posts via the [new review](//hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/review) feature on Biblical Hermeneutics.
2. Started writing a comment on an answer.
3. Changed my mind and edited it instead.
4. Decided to also comment to explain my edit.  Here's what it looked like:

   [image: Before hovering over the "add comment" link.]
5. Clicked on the "add comment" link.  My screen capture utility removed the cursor, so you can mentally add the pointing hand cursor to the image hovering over "add comment":

   [image: While hovering over the "add comment" link.]
6. Nothing happens.  No comment box appears, no error, nothing.

What I expected to happen was that a comment box would show up so that I could add a comment.  In fact, when I go back to the [URL](//hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/294) in another tab, that's exactly what I get:

[image: What I hoped would happen.]

If it matters, I'm using Google Chrome version 22.0.1.229.79 m.  (Wow, those are some mighty long version numbers.  While checking to see which version I have, I see there's another version available.  I'll try updating and see if I can reproduce the bug with another post on some site.)

---

After updating Chrome, I found the same bug on a "Late Answer" review.

I abused one of the answers in my review queue and sure enough, the bug crops up if you do step #2 (start writing a comment), but doesn't show up if you just start editing.

Comment: I just reproduced this with Chrome latest.

Comment: Can't you poke a dev now with a sharp stick, Jon? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: That would be breaking [our promise](http://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/84398/full-stack-web-developer). If this is still a problem (and honestly, I don't even remember writing this question), I'll see who I can ping (softly and gently).

Comment: @JonEricson lol, thanks!